# How to make file permission "read public" while uploading file on S3 by TransferManager using java?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, file-upload

I am want to make my file read permission public while uploading file on s3.
i am using -

```
TransferManager tm = TransferManagerBuilder.standard().withS3Client(s3Client).build();
            ObjectMetadata metadata = new ObjectMetadata();
            metadata.setCacheControl("max-age=2592000, must-revalidate");
            Upload upload = tm.upload(props.getProperty("aws.bucket.name"), keyName,
                    new File(rootPath + SUFFIX + fileName));
            upload.waitForCompletion();
```

Can you please help how can i use **ACL** ?

Comment: I think this is up to the bucket policy

Answer (score 0):

Use the alternate [upload(PutObjectRequest)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/transfer/TransferManager.html#upload-com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.PutObjectRequest-) method. When you use this upload variant, you supply a [PutObjectRequest](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/PutObjectRequest.html) which you construct with the bucket, key, and file and you can then attach a canned ACL using [withCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/PutObjectRequest.html#withCannedAcl-com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.CannedAccessControlList-). For example:

```
PutObjectRequest por = new PutObjectRequest(bucket, key, file)
    .withCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead);
Upload upload = tm.upload(por);
upload.waitForCompletion();
```

Other alternatives include:

- set the ACL afterwards using `s3Client.setObjectAcl(bucketName, keyName, acl)`
- switch to using the Transfer Manager's [uploadFileList()](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/transfer/TransferManager.html#uploadFileList-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.io.File-java.util.List-com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.ObjectMetadataProvider-com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.ObjectTaggingProvider-com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.ObjectCannedAclProvider-) method which supports a canned ACL provider option.

Comment: can you please tell me exactly where i have to add that code ?? still confused

Comment: Set the ACL explicitly after the upload has completed. Or replace the `upload` call with the `uploadFileList` variant.

Comment: I would assume that you can supply a null metadata provider if you don’t need to set metadata, but you’ll have to verify. The other approach of explicitly setting the ACL after upload may be simpler.

Comment: can you please tell me how can i add acl in uploadFileList()  method ?

Comment: Have determined that there is a better solution, which is to use the `upload()` variant that accepts a PutObjectRequest, because you can apply ACLs to that.